# Default Function in PHP

Tags: php, activerecord

I'm trying to implement an *ActiveRecord* for PHP, but I'm trying to make it as simple as possible for the user to implement new Models.
A class `User extends ActiveRecord`, and the table name is set automatically (User -> users).

But there are some static methods, such as `User::find($id)`. In this case, the `__construct()` is not invoked. In all static methods, I have to call some functions manually (database connection, etc).

I'd like to know if there is some kind of function that is called every single time: when the class is instantiated or when some static function is called, so I could group these functions inside only one function.

Thanks in advance

Comment: a function that's called when a class is instantiated? the constructor, perhaps? For static functions, no such beast. you'd have to wrap the static function in ANOTHER function and call the wrapper instead.

Comment: I guess that's the solution. As simple as it is. Thanks =)